Engle-Granger cointegration test critical values
I am conducting the Engle-Granger cointegration test on a system of three time series: logged spot exchange rates, logged domestic price index, and logged foreign price index. I would like to use corrected small-sample critical values, see MacKinnon (2010). I am not sure which asymptotic critical values provided by MacKinnon to start with. I think I know how to calculate the small sample correction, but I am at a loss as to which asymptotic CVs to pick. I would like to estimate my first-step OLS regressions without an intercept and without a trend and do this three times, each time with a different dependent variable. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
